# How to migrate coredata model, deleting entity and saving into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, migration, nsuserdefaults

How to migrate coredata model to new one with this feature:

The original model contains an entity "user" which contains only 1 row data. All I want is to remove this entity and save this data into `NSUserDefaults`.

This is not a lightweight migration. I'm using `NSMigrationManager` trying to save the results before it has been removed, but I haven't got it working yet.

Could you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't sound like you need to use any migration.  Just retrieve the value and save it in NSUserDefaults and just ignore the entity from that point on.  Maybe remove it in some future update using lightweight migration.

Comment: This wont really work. If you have a user moving from a previous version (before you save it to NSUserDefaults) to a future one (When you drop the table via LightWeight), he will "skip" this step and you app will probably crash, since there is no Defaults nor LightWeight.
There has to be a way of doing it via NSMigrationManager.

Comment: OK so forget the 'Maybe remove it in some future version' then and just ignore that table once the value has been saved in defaults, or is there some reason that's not an option.